# Return name of data frame from function

Tags: r

I have the following function where there is only one parameter, `df`. `df` is dataframe:

```
test_function <- function(df) {
    df_name <- df #get name of dataframe (does not work)
    df_name
  }

test_function(mtcars)
```

How do I return name of the dataset from this function? For `test_function(mtcars)` I need to assign string `mtcars` to `df_name`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the combo `substitute` + `deparse`

```
test_function <- function(df)
    deparse(substitute(df))

test_function(mtcars)
##[1] "mtcars"
```

Answer (score 2):

Another option is to use `??match.call`

> returns a call in which all of the specified arguments are specified by their full names.

```
test_function <- function(df){
  as.list(match.call())[-1]  
}

test_function(mtcars)
$df
mtcars
```